# Azure Iot Edge - Communicate from a module to a host network device

Tags: docker-compose, azure-iot-edge

I'm trying to have a TcpStream with a device on the host network from a module.
Since the module is on Bridge network, how I can do that ?

I tried to add createOptions configuration

```
"createOptions": {
  "NetworkingConfig": {
    "EndpointsConfig": {
      "host": {}
    }
  },
  "HostConfig": {
    "NetworkMode": "host"
  }
}
```

but I get this error when iotedgehubdev run

```
ERROR: 'network_mode' and 'networks' cannot be combined
ERROR: Error while executing command: docker-compose -f C:\ProgramData\iotedgehubdev\data\data\docker-compose.yml pull edgeHubDev. Command '['docker-compose', '-f', 'C:\\ProgramData\\iotedgehubdev\\data\\data\\docker-compose.yml', 'pull', 'edgeHubDev']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the log, you are using iotedgehubdev to run the edge solution in simulator. However, iotedgehubdev does not support "host" mode network. The support is in backlog, and will be supported in the next release.

Comment: Here the link of the issue open in github:
https://github.com/Azure/iotedgehubdev/issues/183